# TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined ....src/pages/index.js in Gatsby

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, gatsby, graphql-js

I am getting data as `undefined` from props in `..src/pages/index.js` (It's outside of `components` folder). However, I'm getting data in GraphiQL. I'm new to Gatsby. How do I get data from props?

....src/pages/index.js

```
import { Link, graphql } from "gatsby"

const IndexPage = ({ data }) => (
  <>
    {console.log("data: ", data)} //data: undefined
  </>
)

export const query = graphql`
  {
    img: file(relativePath: { eq: "default-background.jpeg" }) {
      childImageSharp {
        fluid {
          ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid_traceSVG
        }
      }
    }
  }
`

export default IndexPage
```

---

GraphiQL (in browser):

```
{
 img: file(relativePath: {eq: "default-background.jpeg"}) {
   childImageSharp {
     fluid {
       src
     }
   }
 }
}
```

response from GraphiQL:

```
  "data": {
    "img": {
      "childImageSharp": {
        "fluid": {
          "src": "/static/0b5a2394b40bdf231dc6685a512baeff/bc3a8/default-background.jpg"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

my aim is to get `data.img.childImageSharp.fluid` from props `data`

**gatsby-config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  siteMetadata: {
    title: `Regular Joe's`,
    description: `some description.`,
    author: `@gatsbyjs`,
  },
  plugins: [
    `gatsby-plugin-react-helmet`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `images`,
        path: `${__dirname}/src/images`,
      },
    },
    `gatsby-transformer-sharp`,
    `gatsby-plugin-sharp`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-manifest`,
      options: {
        name: `gatsby-starter-default`,
        short_name: `starter`,
        start_url: `/`,
        background_color: `#663399`,
        theme_color: `#663399`,
        display: `minimal-ui`,
        icon: `src/images/logo.svg`, // This path is relative to the root of the site.
      },
    },
    // this (optional) plugin enables Progressive Web App + Offline functionality
    // To learn more, visit: https://gatsby.dev/offline
    // `gatsby-plugin-offline`,
  ],
}
```

Comment: Don't you need to connect your `IndexPage` to graphQL somehow.

Comment: How would I do that ? I'm new to gatsby,  can't get it .I followed a tutorial which is similar to https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/page-query/

Comment: Show us your `gatsby-config.js`. You should have `gatsby-source-filesystem` that points to your image file. Do you have this plugin `https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-source-filesystem/` in your `gatsby-config.js`?

Comment: @EliteRaceElephant I just added ```gatsby-config.js```.  yes I have that plugin installed.

Comment: Try `console.log(data);` instead of `console.log("data:", data);`. Can you see the object now?

Comment: @EliteRaceElephant yes I have tried that before posting question. I always get ```undefined```

Comment: Your setup seems fine to me. Did you try `gatsby clean` and `gatsby build` to update your query?

Comment: @EliteRaceElephant I have exited gatsby server and tried ```gatsby develope``` several times though. let me try ```gatsby clean``` and ```gatsby build```

Comment: @EliteRaceElephant I get error when i tried ```gatsby build```. ..```Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

  TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined```

Comment: I do know the literal meaning of the error ```Cannot read property 'length' of undefined``` but in this case, I don't know what caused this error though. do you have any idea about the error?

Comment: You seem to have everything set up correctly. Could you try logging the whole `props` object?

Comment: i just found out. it was a typo

Answer (score 0):

It was all because of a typo.. I forgot **d** in  *GatsbyImageSharpFluid_trace**d**SVG*

```
export const query = graphql`
  {
    img: file(relativePath: { eq: "default-background.jpeg" }) {
      childImageSharp {
        fluid {
          ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid_tracedSVG //there was a typo in GatsbyImageSharpFluid_traceSVG
        }
      }
    }
  }`
```